# How to call modules methods by name?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.4

I have module with some logic handlers

```
 - handlers
   - __init__.py
   - items.py (with class Items)
   - users.py (with class Users)
 - app.py
```

In main script `app.py` I need to create instance of Items or Users class and call some action. Dynamically, by some params like `{ collection: "items", method: "get" }`

```
oItems = items.Items()
oItems.get()
```

I know how to load all handlers from module: `from handlers import *`, but I don't know how to create instance of `collection` class and call method.

Without dynamic collection it would be

```
method = getattr(items.Items(), 'get')
method()
```

But create an instance - is a problem for me. I'm trying

```
 oItems = type('items.Items', (), {})
```

but it create instance for `__main__` module, not `handlers`

Comment: The instance will always _belong_ to the namespace/scope that it is created in. Maybe try creating a new module attribute with an assignment ```handler.thing = item.Items()```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modules are just objects with attributes, really. As such you can dynamically retrieve those attributes:

```
 collection_module = getattr(handlers, 'items')
 collection_class = getattr(collection_module, 'Items')
 collection = collection_class()
```

You could just store the in a dictionary for easier lookup:

```
 handlers_mapping = {'items': items.Items, 'users': users.Users}
```

and then use `handlers_mapping[type_name]()` or similar.

Comment: Do you grok what the OP is trying to accomplish?

Comment: @wwii: yes, change a string like `items` or `users` (or perhaps `items.Items` and `users.Users` to the class object from a module in the `handlers` package. Then create an instance and dynamically call a method on it.

Comment: I'm not sure something like that would have occurred to me. Would you mind, if possible within the limits of a comment, give a use case where that would be advantageous?

Comment: @wwii: command dispatch (mapping remote client calls to executable code), configuration directives, etc. Anything that can only communicate primitive datatypes but where you want to execute code based no the directives, basically.